# Creating a subset of an existing mongo db database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodump

This query is related to building a small MongoDB test database from a large existing database.

My plan to execute this is as follows:

a) Use mongodump with an aggregate query which specifies my conditions for the records to be copied over to the test database.

Will this idea work? From what I have read on forums, using a MongoDB query as is in a mongodump command will not work.

Any guidance on this is most appreciated.

Comment: You can't use an aggregate (pipeline) query if that's what you mean. This seems easy enough to try ... did you try it with your data and the query you want to use?

Comment: I had an aggregate query in mind. Thanks for giving the heads up. I will figure out another way and keep this thread updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command to get the subset of the DB.

```
mongodump --query "your query here"
```

For more information read the mongodump documentation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongodump/).

Comment: Thank you Parvin. I will try this out and get back to this thread if I face any issues with the query i require.